# Fetch random data from API without refreshing the page in react axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios

How can I retrieve a specific data based on a key value passed to base API url. Here is the code for the component which retrieves the data using refreshing the page.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import 'react-confirm-alert/src/react-confirm-alert.css'; // Import css
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { id, pid } from '../../../../auth/store/actions/index.js';
import http from '../../../../resources/http.js';

const AdminUpload = () => {
  const baseURL =
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/business_process/get-my-business-process';
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
  const [client, setClient] = useState();
  const [showHide, setShowHide] = useState(false);
  const handleModalShowHide = () => setShowHide(!showHide);
  const [company_name, setCompany] = useState();
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [business_process, setBusinessProcess] = useState();
  let type = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cyber-minds'));
  let clientID = type.user.client.id;
  const [datas, setDatas] = useState([]);
  const processId = useSelector((state) => state.pid);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    http
      .get(baseURL)
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.data);
      })
      .then(
        (response) => {},
        (err) => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      );
    http
      .get(
        `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/business_process/get-business-impact/${processId}`
      )
      .then((response) => {
        setDatas(response.data);
      })
      .then(
        (response) => {},
        (err) => {
          console.log('No Data To Show');
        }
      )
      .catch((err) => {
        return false;
      });
  }, []);
  console.log(data);
  const handleFile = (e) => {
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    setFile(file);
  };
  const handleUploadFile = (e) => {
    let myfile = file;

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', myfile);
    formData.append('business_process', business_process);
    formData.append('businuss impact analysis', 'financial');
    http({
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/business_process/upload-business-impact-excel-by-clientadmin',
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      data: formData,
    }).then(
      (response) => {
        alert('File uploaded Sesscessfully');
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  };
  const deleteBusinessImpact = (e) => {
    let myfile = file;

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', myfile);
    formData.append('business_process', business_process);
    formData.append('businuss impact analysis', 'financial');
    http({
      url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/business_process/get-business-impact/${processId}`,
      method: 'DELETE',
      mode: 'cors',
    }).then(
      (response) => {
        alert('File Deleted Successfully');
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  };
  const refresh = () => {
    window.location.reload();
  };
  console.log('process id', processId);
  const DisplayData = datas?.map((asset) => {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{asset.hierarchy}</td>
        <td>{asset.business_assets}</td>
        <td>{asset.asset_name}</td>
        <td>{asset.vendors}</td>
        <td>{asset.product}</td>
        <td>{asset.version}</td>
        <td>{asset.cpe}</td>
        <td>{asset.asset_type}</td>
        <td>{asset.asset_categorization}</td>
        <td>{asset._regulations}</td>
        <td>{asset.asset_risk}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  });
  return (
    <>
      <div className=" flex flex-col space-y-6 justify-center mt-10 items-center">
        <h4>Uplaod Business Impact Analysis File</h4>
        <div class="search_categories w-96">
          <div class="select">
            <select
              value={business_process}
              onChange={(e) => {
                setBusinessProcess(e.target.value);
                dispatch(pid(e.target.value));
              }}
            >
              <option>Select Business Process</option>
              {data?.map((x, y) => (
                <option value={x.id}>{x.name}</option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        {/* <h1>Upload Business Impact Analysis File</h1> */}
        <div className="flex space-x-4">
          <input type="file" name="file" onChange={(e) => handleFile(e)} />
        </div>
        <button
          className="color bg p-2 rounded-md w-72"
          type="button"
          onClick={(e) => refresh()} //show button with reloading the page
        >
          Show
        </button>
        <button
          className="color bg p-2 rounded-md w-72"
          type="button"
          onClick={(e) => handleUploadFile(e)}
        >
          Clear and Upload new file
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="z-100">
        <div className="mt-36 flex space-x-10 justify-end items-end mr-16 text-lg">
          {/* <IconButton className="border-b">
            <EditIcon style={{ fontSize: 40 }} />
          </IconButton> */}

          <button
            className="color bg p-2 rounded-md"
            type="button"
            onClick={(e) => {
              deleteBusinessImpact(e);
              refresh();
              alert('Deleted Successfully');
            }}
          >
            Delete All Data
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className="text-black">
          <div className="rounded overflow-hidden flex  justify-center items-center">
            <table class="GeneratedTables">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th className="detail text-2xl">Hierarchy</th>
                  <th className="color text-2xl">Business assets</th>
                  <th className="detail text-2xl">Asset Name</th>
                  <th className="color text-2xl">Vendors</th>
                  <th className="detail text-2xl">Product</th>
                  <th className="color text-2xl">Version</th>
                  <th className="detail text-2xl">CPE</th>
                  <th className="color text-2xl">Asset Type</th>
                  <th className="detail text-2xl">Asset Categorization</th>
                  <th className="color text-2xl">Regulations</th>
                  <th className="detail text-2xl">Asset Risk</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>{DisplayData}</tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default AdminUpload;
```

In the above code, when I click show button It reloads the page and retrieve the data based on the key value passed into the base URL. Without reloading the page, the data is not showing up. That's why I added reload functionality.

How can I implement show button to show data without actually reloading the page?

Thanks

Comment: Is `processId` the key value you're mentioning? If not can't you just put that in the dependency array of the effect that's doing the fetching? When it changes the effect will run again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are only updating the data in the backend, thus necessitating the "refresh" to refetch the data. Instead of reloading the app you could just refetch the data.

Refactor the two GET requests of in the `useEffect` hook into a standalone function to be called by the hook and at the end of the form submission.

Example:

```
const fetchData = () => {
  http
    .get(baseURL)
    .then((response) => {
      setData(response.data);
    })
    .then(
      (response) => {},
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  http
    .get(
      `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/business_process/get-business-impact/${processId}`
    )
    .then((response) => {
      setDatas(response.data);
    })
    .then(
      (response) => {},
      (err) => {
        console.log('No Data To Show');
      }
    )
    .catch((err) => {
      return false;
    });
};

useEffect(() => fetchData(), []);

...

<button
  className="color bg p-2 rounded-md w-72"
  type="button"
  onClick={fetchData}
>
  Show
</button>

...

<button
  className="color bg p-2 rounded-md"
  type="button"
  onClick={(e) => {
    deleteBusinessImpact(e);
    fetchData();
    alert('Deleted Successfully');
  }}
>
  Delete All Data
</button>
```